# Where to find current circuit in tor browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, circuit

Have been using tor browser in past, upgraded to latest version (10.0.12) and i found that tor button aka. onion icon addon is removed from tor browser since 9.0 - you can find it in changelog here: https://blog.torproject.org/new-release-tor-browser-90. My intuition told me that i could find in settings in `Options -> Tor` when it was integrated directly there, but have not found anything about circuits. I want to view current circuit, maybe set custom circuit or at least ending node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the lock icon in the top left corner and you should see the current circuit in the Tor Browser.
[image]

Once you click on the lock, you should see whether the website you are using has a secure connection or not. You will also see the current circuit being used.

[image]

You can click new circuit if you want to connect to the site from different servers, though Tor does this automatically for you for every website you visit. I hope this helps!

For more information, see the links below.

- https://support.torproject.org/tbb/#tbb-2
- https://support.torproject.org/tbb/#tbb-40

You can also view the design implementation of the Tor browser here:
https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/.